# Add rule to validator to not allow the integer 0

Tags: validation, cakephp-3.0

How would I add a rule to my validator to throw an error when 0 is entered. Here is the current default validation function:

```
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
    {
    $validator
        ->add('quantity', 'valid', ['rule' => 'numeric'])
        ->add('quantity', 'validValue', ['rule' => ['range', 1, PHP_INT_MAX], 'message' => _('Cannot have quantity of 0.')])
        ->requirePresence('quantity', 'create')
        ->notEmpty('quantity');

    return $validator;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does that exactly, if user will input 0 for quantity, your error message will be thrown.

The below line of code is sufficient for that.

```
$validator->add('title', 'validValue', ['rule' => ['range', 1, PHP_INT_MAX], 'message' => _('Cannot have quantity of 0.')])
```